# Php pop up successfull message after redirect to another page

Tags: php

I'm currently working on the online booking system.In the script below, I have build a script which takes all the details and on success redirect it to another page.
My question is how do i pop up a successful message on header page.

Here is the script

```
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO bookings (customerid, pname,cnumber, paddress, daddress, via, pdate, hours, mins, luggage, vtype, pnum, info) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
      $statement->bind_param('issssssiiisis', $user_id, $pname, $number, $pickupaddress, $dropaddress, $via, $date, $hours, $minutes, $luggages, $vtype, $passengers, $additional);

      if($statement->execute()){
            header('Location: activebookings.php');
        }
      }else{
      die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
      }
      $statement->close();
      }
```

Comment: Popups are done with javascript. If you don't know how to create a popup - google please, there tons of plugins for popups.

Comment: Yeh i don't mind using jquery for that but question is how to achieve it ? I only want pop up message when $statement is successfull

Comment: Achieve what? What is unclear in message `find a popup plugin`?

Comment: I only want pop up message when $statement is successfull

Comment: When the statement is successful you move to `activebookings.php`. On this page use javascript and create a popup.

Comment: You would not do that in PHP... you can store a session variable with they key `session_start(); $_SESSION['success'] = "Success!!";` and somewhere at the bottom `if(isset($_SESSION['success'])) { echo '<div class="some_fance_div">'.$_SESSION['success'].'</div>'; }` to have an alert container or a javascript snippet initializing an alert (yuk).. OR use jQuery's [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) with a php script handlich your ajax request.

Comment: @Yolo Cheers for that just gonna try now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use sessions for that.

```
if($statement->execute()){
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Your message here";
    header('Location: activebookings.php');
}
```

(you may need to call `session_start()` first, if you're not using sessions yet at this point)

Then on your activebookings.php page read it from the session (again, you may need to call `session_start()` first):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $_SESSION['message'] . '");</script>';
    unset($_SESSION['message']);
}
```

You'll want to unset the message from the session, to make sure your visitors don't get the popup again if they refresh the page.

Comment: Cheers for that just gonna try now

Answer (score 1):

you can use a $_SESSION variable before the header, set a session variable called status to 1 or something like that and then on activebookings check for the session variable and if it exists you can echo the javascript needed to popup a modal.

on booking page

```
$_SESSION['status'] = 1;
```

on activebooking (where you want popup)

```
$status = $_SESSION['status']

if($status)
echo '<script>popup();</script>'
```

Comment: Cheers for that just gonna try now

Answer (score 0):

Use the echo to display a js alert like this:

```
echo "<script>alert('Success');</script>";
```

If you want to put session data into the alert do this just be sure that your message doesn't have any " or ' to not interfere in the syntax

Like this:

```
echo "</script>alert("'.$_SESSION['your data'].'");</script>";
```

Hope i have helped!

Comment: Thanks for that :)